# How to restart a stopped RabbitMQ service that is hosted on amazon ECS cluster?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, amazon-ecs, amazon-ebs

I've various micro services hosted on amazon ECS cluster with EC2. The micro services are running on the docker container. Among these services I've a rabbitMQ service which has been stopped. Not sure exactly what caused it to stop.

[image]

Please let me know how can I restart the stopped service rabbitMQ. I've already tried restarting the EBS but the issue seem to continue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to start tasks on ECS: with [the `runTask` API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_run_task.html) and with [the `service` API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html). The former is a one-off start (typically used for batch jobs etc). If the container (for whatever reasons) stops, it will be gone. The latter is a way to start tasks (1 or more) that are part of a long running service. You tell ECS you want to run a service with `n` tasks and ECS will keep `n` tasks running all the time (i.e. if one or more stops ECS will start one or more tasks to meet `n`). Note the strong EBS integration is lacking and for you specific use case you may need to create a service with 1 task and constraint it to run on the EC2 instance where you mounted upfront the EBS (this will allow ECS to restart the task and find the data hosted on EBS on the host).